# Adding auto scroll to a fixed element when browser is too small

Tags: html, css, overflow, fixed

I'm trying to give a fixed element a scroll bar only if the browser is too small to show all of its contents.

I also have a fixed footer at the bottom of the page, and i would ideally like the scrolling to start once the contents of the fixed element go behind the footer.

Here is a link to a simply example of my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/alsweeet/pGFzF/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>       
<div id="footer"></div>

#container{
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000;
}
```

The container is a certain distance from the top, so I can't simply give the height a percentage.

I'm guessing this is quite a common issue, but I have never come accross it, and couldn't find the magic words to squeeze the answer out of google.

Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Comment: Somehthing like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axXGD/) is OK?  AFAIK, you need a fixed height to put a scroll with overflow.

Comment: yea i think what i'm trying to achieve isn't possible. I need the scroll bar to only appear once the content is too large. I might have to change the distance from top into a percentage. then that will allow me to specify the height of the container as a percentage.

Comment: And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3uNh/)? Also, the scrollbar only will appear if the content if bigger than the container.

Comment: Unfortunately that still shows the the scroll bar when the page has enough room to show all the content. I need it to show the contents if the page has room. Like this, but without using percentages for the heights http://jsfiddle.net/alsweeet/rXrEU/1/

Comment: Definitely, I don't understand you. Your jsfiddle is like mine, isn't it? Do you want that the div auto-adjust to the content and if it higher than a certain height put a scrollbar?

Comment: No the difference is that your jsfiddle will always show the scrollbar, even if it doesn't need one. if you adjust the height on mine, the scroll bar will disappear once the container is high enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anybody has the same problem, I went with the percentage option. 
Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/alsweeet/rXrEU/1

Ideally i would have liked to have kept the distance from top as a fixed height, but i don't think this is possible to allow the scrolling to work correctly.

```
#container{
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 70%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

#footer{
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000;
}
```